# Socket Programming in C: UDP send() taking 6 - 260 micro sec, how to make it faster

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, wireshark

Using `SOCK_DGRAM` for `UDP` sockets

All packets are `22 bytes` in length (ie `64 including headers`)

**client.c**

```
...
    no_of_packets--;
    sprintf(buf, "#:!0 rem");
    sprintf(buf, format , buf);
    sprintf(buf_aux, "#: 0 rem");
    sprintf(buf_aux, format , buf_aux);
    buf[MAX_LINE-1] = '\0';
    buf_aux[MAX_LINE-1] = '\0';
    len = strlen(buf) + 1;
    send(s, buf, len, 0);
    while (no_of_packets-- > 1) {
        nanosleep(&T, NULL);
        send(s, buf, len, 0);
    }
    send(s, buf_aux, len, 0);
```

**server.c**

```
...
while(1) {
        if (len = recv(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)){
            // do nothing
        }
}
```

When I open `Wireshark` to see avg delay between the packets which are sent,

I can see the following:

- *MIN* delay:  0.000 006 795 sec => *6 micro sec*
- *MAX* delay:  0.000 260 952 sec => *260 micro sec*
- But I want to send packets every *512 nano sec* (ie., 0.512 micro sec).

> **How** can I achieve this speed?

Comment: Easy - do not use Linux or Windows or any other general-purpose OS.  You need a fast microcontroller/DSP, dedicated driver code.  Read the hardware manuals and data sheets, then design your software driver appropriately.

Comment: Note that loop `while (no_of_packets-- > 1)` executes `no_of_packets - 1` times.

Comment: `sprintf(buf, format , buf);`  <<-- it is not allowed to write to the buffer you are reading from.

Comment: `if (len = recv(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)){` <<-- recv() can return `-1` , too.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can probably do that with a kernel bypass network stack, such as [PF_RING ZC (Zero Copy)](https://www.ntop.org/products/packet-capture/pf_ring/pf_ring-zc-zero-copy/), and FIFO real-time threads that run on isolated cores that:

1. Fill a packet to send in the network card buffer.
2. Busy-wait till the next time point.
3. Emit the prepared packet into the wire.
4. Go to 1.

You may also find [Understanding PCIe performance for end host networking](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/srg/netos/projects/pcie-bench/neugebauer2018understanding.pdf) white-paper useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will take a look at the documents and see